# Can we update a row in Hive Table Using Spark-SQL

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

Tried like this :

```
HiveContext  hiveql=new org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveContext(ctx);
hiveql.sql("UPDATE sparkexamples.employee SET empname='Sreeharsha' WHERE empid='1210'");
```

**Submitting Job:**

```
./bin/spark-submit 
    --class com.spark.examples.SparkUpdateHiveContext 
    --master local[4] /home/hadoop/SparkHIveUpdate.jar
```

Get the Following Error : Any suggestions please

```
16/07/01 11:45:38 INFO parse.ParseDriver: Parse Completed
Exception in thread "main" org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: 
Unsupported language features in query: 
UPDATE sparkexamples.employee SET empname='Sreeharsha' WHERE empid='1210'
TOK_UPDATE_TABLE 1, 0,16, 7
 TOK_TABNAME 1, 2,4, 7
   sparkexamples 1, 2,2, 7
   employee 1, 4,4, 21
 TOK_SET_COLUMNS_CLAUSE 1, 6,10, 41
   = 1, 8,10, 41
     TOK_TABLE_OR_COL 1, 8,8, 34
       empname 1, 8,8, 34
     'Sreeharsha' 1, 10,10, 42
 TOK_WHERE 1, 12,16, 66
   = 1, 14,16, 66
     TOK_TABLE_OR_COL 1, 14,14, 61
       empid 1, 14,14, 61
     '1210' 1, 16,16, 67
scala.NotImplementedError: No parse rules for TOK_UPDATE_TABLE:
TOK_UPDATE_TABLE 1, 0,16, 7
 TOK_TABNAME 1, 2,4, 7
   sparkexamples 1, 2,2, 7
   employee 1, 4,4, 21
 TOK_SET_COLUMNS_CLAUSE 1, 6,10, 41
   = 1, 8,10, 41
     TOK_TABLE_OR_COL 1, 8,8, 34
       empname 1, 8,8, 34
     'Sreeharsha' 1, 10,10, 42
 TOK_WHERE 1, 12,16, 66
   = 1, 14,16, 66
     TOK_TABLE_OR_COL 1, 14,14, 61
       empid 1, 14,14, 61
     '1210' 1, 16,16, 67
org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveQl$.nodeToPlan(HiveQl.scala:1086)
```

Comment: As far I know we can not update hive table using spark 1.6. But as alternative  you can read data as dataframe and do modification on that data and save it back to hdfs.

Comment: does spark/hive rewrite only the affected partitions? if so, how can I achieve that ?

Comment: Provided:
> Dynamic partitioning is enabled in Hive
> DataFrame save mode is overwrite
> DataFrame is partitioned
then it will overwrite only the relevant partitions.